# Yammer - User Profile Picture In Embedded Topic Feed

Tags: yammer

I have a website that shows all the posts from Yammer regarding a particular topic in the Yammer Embedded Feed. However, the feed does not show the profile picture of the User who has posted in that topic.

Is there any way I can achieve this feature? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your container is at least 400 pixels wide. Otherwise, I believe it uses a "skinny" version of the display which does not include the profile photos. See this page for more info: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/feed-events (paragraph Skinny mode).

Corinne